# SQL select doesn't return results as I want

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datatable

I'm an amateur at SQL and I need your help. After "Select" at 3rd row I should get

```
Ivo |Ivić| NULL
```

but I get all 3 nulls. Help me, where is my mistake? I tried to check my code for like 10 times and still can't see the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE Prijatelj 
(
    ID_prijatelja INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ImePrijatelja NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PrezPrijatelja NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE DVD 
(
    ID_DVD INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ImeDVD NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Posudio 
(
    ID_prijatelja INT NOT NULL 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES prijatelj(ID_prijatelja),
    ID_DVD INT NOT NULL
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dvd(ID_DVD),
    datumPosudbe DATETIME NOT NULL,
    datumPovratka DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT PK_posudba 
         PRIMARY KEY (ID_Prijatelja, ID_DVD, datumPosudbe)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE Posudio 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Posudba_prije_Povratka CHECK (datumPosudbe < datumPovratka)

INSERT INTO Prijatelj (ImePrijatelja, PrezPrijatelja)
VALUES ('Ana', 'Anić'), 
       ('Ivo', 'Ivić'),
       ('Marko', 'Marić')
GO

INSERT INTO DVD (ImeDVD)
VALUES ('Avengers: Infinity War'),
       ('Interstellar'),
       ('Inception')
GO

INSERT INTO Posudio(ID_prijatelja, ID_DVD, datumPosudbe, datumPovratka)
VALUES (1, 1, '2019-01-5','2019-01-14'),
       (2, 2, '2018-12-16','2019-01-8'),
       (2, 3, dateadd(day, -30, getdate()), NULL)
GO

SELECT
    d.ImeDVD AS 'Naziv DVD-a',
    pr.ImePrijatelja AS 'Ime',
    pr.PrezPrijatelja AS 'Prezime',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, datumPosudbe, datumPovratka) AS 'Dana posuđen'
FROM 
    DVD AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM Posudio 
     WHERE datumPovratka IS NOT NULL) AS po ON d.ID_DVD = po.ID_DVD
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    prijatelj AS pr ON po.ID_prijatelja = pr.ID_prijatelja


SELECT 
    pr.ImePrijatelja AS 'Ime', pr.PrezPrijatelja AS 'Prezime'
FROM 
    prijatelj pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Posudio po ON pr.ID_prijatelja = po.ID_prijatelja
WHERE 
    po.ID_prijatelja IS NULL
GO
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Um, how are the table create rules insufficient for conveying the schema?  I thought we were only missing the actual output and expected output.

Comment: Avengers: Infinity War Ana Anić 9
Interstellar Ivo Ivić 23
Inception NULL NULL NULL

Comment: Expected Avengers: Infinity War Ana Anić 9
Interstellar Ivo Ivić 23
Inception Ivo Ivić NULL

Comment: @EdGrimm That is a standard comment I have for new guys. Yes he have schemas but didnt include the expected output and the other links have some sugestion on how improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outer Joins are tricky, for an *amateur* you're quite good :-)

You need to join to `posudio` without that WHERE-condition:

```
SELECT
   d.ImeDVD AS 'Naziv DVD-a',
   pr.ImePrijatelja AS 'Ime',
   pr.PrezPrijatelja AS 'Prezime',
   datediff(DAY, datumPosudbe, datumPovratka) AS 'Dana posuđen'
FROM DVD AS d
LEFT JOIN Posudio  AS po 
  ON d.ID_DVD = po.ID_DVD
LEFT JOIN prijatelj AS pr
  ON po.ID_prijatelja = pr.ID_prijatelja
```